# Change vertical scrollbar location in multi-monitor setup?

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors

I have a 2 monitor setup with monitor 1 on the left and monitor 2 on the right. I would like vertical scrollbars to be on the left side of windows on monitor 1 and on the right side of windows in monitor 2. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 2):

The location of the scroll bars is determined by the application. I haven't come across anything that would let Windows override this.

Most applications aren't multi-monitor aware. They don't check which monitor they are running on, as even today the vast majority of users still only have a single screen.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible in Windows 7.  The only way I can see you being able to do this is with some sort of shell replacement (lots of work, potentially messing up your system, etc.)

The closest you can get is if you use firefox you could move the scroll bar to the left side... but that applies to all instances of firefox so the on on your monitor 2 would have scroll on the left also.  http://www.askvg.com/how-to-move-scrollbar-from-right-to-left-in-mozilla-firefox-30/ is an article on how to do that.

I wish there were a better answer.